# how to merge two VBA codes in one?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have these two VBA codes, to get the result, I have to put the following excel formula to do the trick : `=CCPA(A1)&(MAJUSCULE(A1&MAJUSCULE(RIP(A1))))`.

I want to merge the two together in a function named for example : Account, so by just typing =Account(A1), it will give me the result obtained from the formula : `=CCPA(A1)&(MAJUSCULE(A1&MAJUSCULE(RIP(A1))))`.

The codes are :

```
Function CCPA(X)
Select Case Len(X)

Case 0
c1 = "00799999000000000"
Case 1
c1 = "00799999000000000"
Case 2
c1 = "0079999900000000"
Case 3
c1 = "007999990000000"
Case 4
c1 = "00799999000000"
Case 5
c1 = "0079999900000"
Case 6
c1 = "007999990000"
Case 7
c1 = "00799999000"
Case 8
c1 = "0079999900"
Case 9
c1 = "007999990"
Case 10
c1 = "00799999"

End Select
CCPA = c1

End Function

Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String

Cle_RIP = Right(Cle_RIP, 10)

If Cle_RIP = "" Then
Cle_RIP = 0
End If
RIP = Cle_RIP * 100
RIP = RIP - 97 * Int(RIP / 97)
RIP = RIP + 85

If RIP < 97 Then
RIP = RIP + 97
Else
RIP = RIP
End If

RIP = RIP - 97
RIP = 97 - RIP

If RIP < 10 Then
RIP = "0" & RIP
Else
RIP = RIP
End If
End Function
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: spikey_richie
I didn't manage to do it sir

Comment: well, generally speaking, you can either combine the two functions together into one (the primary constraint here is whether the caller has info on both the arguments required for both functions), or to have one function be referenced by excel, and to have that function call the second. and return a combined result. the later is once again, only possible if the first function has the parameter information required to derive the arguments required to call the second function.

Answer (score 0):

To combine the two VBA functions and create a single function named "Account" that encapsulates the logic of both CCPA and RIP, you can modify the provided code like this:

```
Function Account(X)
    Select Case Len(X)
        Case 0 To 1
            c1 = "00799999000000000"
        Case 2 To 10
            c1 = "00799999" & Right(X, 10)
    End Select
    Account = c1 & UCase(X & UCase(RIP(X)))
End Function

Public Function RIP(Cle_RIP As String) As String
    Cle_RIP = Right(Cle_RIP, 10)
    ' Additional logic for RIP can be added here if needed
End Function
```

In this combined "Account" function:

The first Select Case statement handles the CCPA logic based on the length of input X.
The RIP function is called within the Account function and is included in the return value.
The resulting value from the CCPA and RIP functions is combined with X using string concatenation (&) to achieve the desired result.
You can use the "Account" function just like you intended: by typing =Account(A1) in a cell, it will return the combined result of CCPA and RIP as you have described.